# How to put DML statements on hold in a database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

Is there a way to put all DML statements to be put on hold until a condition is met?

**Scenario:**
There are multiple users interacting with database simultaneously through a Windows application. Performing all kinds of insert, update, delete actions.

I have a procedure that does something important:

```
Proc_SomeImportantWork
```

When this procedure executes, only this procedure must execute. New entries or modification etc made by any procedure except this must be put on hold or stopped as long as `Proc_SomeImportantWork` is working.

Is this possible? If yes please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: *Why* should it be the only thing to execute? What does it do? This doesn't scale even in small scenarios. If you want to avoid reading "dirty" data there other ways to do this, that don't require locking an entire database. Eg, you can use a transaction with snapshot isolation to see the data as it was when the transaction started, or copy the relevant data to a separate (perhaps temporary) table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if I have have transaction in this `Proc_SomeImportantWork` that used 3 tables,  will it ensure that no new entries will be added or deleted or modified in those three tables as long as this procedure is done processing.  Lets say table A has 10 entries B has 20 entries when procedure started . Lets suppose the procedure runs for 5 mins. And there are other people constantly entering data to these tables while procedure is running.  Will a transaction ensure that procedure works with the original state of the tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the other users' DML, you can use application lock.

If not, open a transaction, issue a noop select on tables you want locked with TABLOCKX hint (`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 1=0 WITH(TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)`). Then run the procedure, from the same session, and commit after it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ddl database trigger like so:

```
create trigger  error2 on database   for CREATE_TABLE,
ALTER_TABLE,
DROP_TABLE 
as
   begin
         if USER_NAME()<>'dbo'
         begin
             RAISERROR('All changes are currently not allowed -                Please     call Mary at x1234
             <schema change>.', 10, 1);
              rollback
          end
end
```

This will create a trigger at the database level which will disallow anyone, except the dbo, from creating, altering or dropping a table until the trigger is deleted or disabled.

When I logged in as a non-dba and tried to create a table this message appeared:

```
All changes are currently not allowed - Please call Mary at x1234
<schema change>.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
```

To see a list of events you can trap please see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542%28v=sql.105%29.aspx and explore around for  additional events you can control.

When you are done you probably want to disable the trigger or you, or Mary, will be getting lots, and lots, of calls.

Comment: It's a DDL trigger you're describing, not DML.